# C++ Values not been stored as needed

Tags: c++, class, compilation

This code is from my "virtual ATM machine" program which deals with customers depositing, checking balance and withdrawing money from their account. When I deposit the money, it displays that it gets deposited.. But... here goes the code before I state my problem:

```
double bankAccount::deposit()
{
      bankAccount b;

       double amt;

       system("cls");
       cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
       cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
       cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";

       cout << "\n\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE: " << balance << endl;
       cout << "\nEnter amount to deposit: ";
       cin >> amt;

       balance = (balance + amt);

       cout << "\nAmount depositted successfully!" << endl;
       cout <<"\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE: " << balance;

       getch();
       customer_actions();
       return balance;

}
```

"customer_actions()" being the main menu for the customers, when I go back on that screen and select the option to check balance, it displays as ZERO. Which means the values didn't get updated from the previous function. Here's my header file which consists of the class file:

```
#ifndef bank
#define bank


using namespace std;


class bankAccount
{
    public:
        int accNo;
        int password;

        double balance;
        double withdrawamt;
        double depositamt;

        char name[20];
        char address[40];
        char username[10];

    public:

        double checkbalance();
        double deposit();
        double withdraw();


    public:
           bankAccount()
           {
              balance = 0; // Is this the reason?
           }    

};


#endif
```

I'm thinking, **when the program switches from one menu to the other, the values get reset-ed.** Any suggestions, dear folks?

Thanks in advance!

CUSTOMER_ACTIONS:

```
int customer_actions()
    {
          bankAccount b;
          int cust_selection;
          system("cls");

   cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
   cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
   cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";
   cout << "                     Please Select option to continue:              \n" << endl << endl;

   cout << "1) Check balance    : Press 1" << endl;
   cout << "2) Withdraw Cash    : Press 2" << endl;
   cout << "3) Deposit Cash     : Press 3" << endl;
   cout << "4) Transfer Cash    : Press 4" << endl;
   cout << "5) Return home      : Press 5" << endl;
   cout << "\nEnter option: ";
   cin >> cust_selection;               


   switch(cust_selection)
   {
      case 1: b.checkbalance();   break;
      case 2: b.withdraw(); break;
      case 3: b.deposit(); break;
      case 4: break;
      case 5: main(); break;   
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see menus here.

Comment: Probably because you're recreating the bankAccount instance over and over...

Comment: We need to see what customer_actions() does.

Comment: You're not showing all of your code. Your assertion that values are reset between calls suggests that you're using multiple `bankAccount` objects.

Comment: We need to see the code that uses the `bankAccount` object

Comment: Does `customer_actions()` define a local variable of `bankAccount` type? then it's every time a new variable since you are calling `customer_actions()` from your `deposit` method. You should have a loop in `customer_actions()` method, and the method shouldn't be called from `bankAccount`'s methods.

Comment: The line of code which displays the zero, why haven't you shown us that?

Comment: I think you might have already tested ur code by commenting the line `balance = 0;`, but still might be getting weird output.
I don't think there is any problem with the code... `cout << "\n\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE: " << balance << endl;` should be zero from ur code what I feel. But after entering the `amt` value still if u r getting `zero` as in ur output; then put the complete code here or at least `customer_actions()`

Comment: Explicitly calling `main()` is forbidden by the C++ standard.

Comment: Your #ifndef bank #define bank is beyond scary. Use long, uppercase-only identifiers for your header guards that are unlikely to conflict with something you might actually use.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (from what I can see) is that you are trying to create an infinite loop where the user can keep pressing making changes on the menu until they exit. However you are going about this by calling `customer_actions()` from within the deposit function.

Try creating an infinite loop in an outer method, then returning from `deposit` without calling `customer_actions()`.

*Following OP edit*

Try this:

```
int main(...)
{
     int result = 0;
     while(result == 0)
     {
         result = customer_actions();
     }
}
```

Now change the switch statement in `customer_actions` to be like this:

```
switch(cust_selection)
{
      case 1: b.checkbalance();   break;
      case 2: b.withdraw(); break;
      case 3: b.deposit(); break;
      case 4: break;
      case 5: return 1; // This is the change
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I added a loop to the switch that calls the customer_actions function and removed the customer_actions() call from the deposit. But hey, the program closes as soon as I deposit money.. when I need it to return  back to the switch. I've added getch() but yeah, nothing works :/ Any suggestions, mate?

Comment: There are three to four fundamental entities: Bank, BankAccount, ATM and maybe Customer, the last depending on how detailed you want your system. ATM realizes the controller and view of the model-view-controller pattern. Bank is in your case just a composite consisting of BankAccounts and maybe conveniently a name. If there just one Bank in your App it could be implemented using a Singleton pattern, otherwise main() or global scope can hold an aggregate of Banks (std::map e.g.). Now delegate the functionality you need to those entities and you have a design.

Comment: OK I have made additional comments in to answer your questions please check the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The bank account `b` you declare in `customer_action` is just valid in function scope.

In addition:

`customer_action` manages given accounts by their interface, accounts should not "manage" `customer_action` (in your case, don't call it from deposit)

You could  easily get a stack overflow the way you coded that.

---

Generally speaking you should try to avoid mixing up model (your accounts) view (the output) and controller (user input) - related code.

Create clean interfaces and call in in a structured manner.

---

In addition:

I first read your bold put question and afterwards attended the code.

The first thing I did then was was trying to find if there is  local redefinition of `double balance`. There is none, but I should not even have had to do so, because there are means to avoid side-effects on instance member variables like `balance`.

Foremost - make them private, not public.

Then:

1. use a prefix like `m_` so `m_balance` that would be or even `m_dblBalance` to indicate the type
2. or prefix all private variables with a `_`,  so `_balance` that would be
3. and/or emphasize each usage of instance member vars by prefixing them with a redundant `this->`

Personally speaking I dislike 1. but use 2. for instance variables.

---

There are many more design and implementation issues, eg. I would discourage `char[]` for strings and recommend using `std::string`, but maybe you start by just ending the marriage of `deposit()` and `customer_actions()` you blessed.